# Calculating statistics directly from a CSV file

Tags: bash, csv

I have a transaction log file in CSV format that I want use to run statistics.  The log has the following fields:

```
date:  Time/date stamp
salesperson:  The username of the person who closed the sale
promo:  sum total of items in the sale that were promotions.
amount:  grand total of the sale
```

I'd like to get the following statistics:

```
salesperson:  The username of the salesperson being analyzed.
minAmount:  The smallest grand total of this salesperson's transaction.
avgAmount:  The mean grand total..
maxAmount:  The largest grand total..
minPromo:  The smallest promo amount by the salesperson.
avgPromo:  The mean promo amount...
```

I'm tempted to build a database structure, import this file, write SQL, and pull out the stats.  I don't need anything more from this data than these stats.  Is there an easier way?  I'm hoping some bash script could make this easy.

Comment: What part of the problem are you having issues with? The statistics themselves? The data structures? The parsing? It doesn't seem like a very hard problem for any scripting language you're comfortable with.

Comment: *cuddles PowerShell* ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could also bang out an awk script to do it. It's only CSV with a few variables.

Comment: Awk's a natural for this - even has begin/end so you can initialize and then calcualte averages easily

Comment: very interesting.  How can I use awk to do a "GROUP BY salesperson"?

Comment: @User1: With an associative array or `asort()` or `asorti()`.

Comment: Done.  This was way easier than building a database.  It was definitely worth beefing up my awk skills!

Answer (score 3):

[TxtSushi](http://keithsheppard.name/txt-sushi) does this:

```
tssql -table trans transactions.csv \
'select
    salesperson,
    min(as_real(amount)) as minAmount,
    avg(as_real(amount)) as avgAmount,
    max(as_real(amount)) as maxAmount,
    min(as_real(promo)) as minPromo,
    avg(as_real(promo)) as avgPromo
from trans
group by salesperson'
```

I have a bunch of [example scripts](http://patch-tag.com/r/keithshep/txt-sushi/snapshot/current/content/pretty/examples) showing how to use it.

Edit: fixed syntax

Comment: +1 This looks much easier.  I'll have to give it a shot next time.  BTW:  Are you an aardvark?

Comment: That's what I was afraid of..I hope your owner doesn't get busted for having you in his home (if you're in the US).  I heard you guys were "especially intelligent" but, wow, answering on SO is quite over the top.  So, is it the sugar that makes you so smart?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the lines in the CSV and use bash script variables to hold your min/max amounts.  For the average, just keep a running total and then divide by the total number of lines (not counting a possible header).

Here are some [useful snippets](http://www.thelinuxblog.com/working-with-csv-files-in-bash/) for working with CSV files in bash.

If your data might be quoted (e.g. because a field contains a comma), processing with bash, sed, etc. becomes much more complex.